# Sphinx autodoc mock imports results in undocumented object

Tags: python, mocking, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am trying to document constants derived from mocked imports (foo.FOO)

foo.py

```
"""Foo module."""


from asdf import qwerty


FOO = qwerty.FOO
"""Foo constant."""


ASDF = 1
"""ASDF."""


def foo():
    """Return foo :py:const:`foo.FOO` :py:const:`foo.ASDF`."""
    return FOO
```

conf.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.pardir))

project = 'sphinx'
copyright = '2021, sphinx'
author = 'sphinx'

extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']
templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = []
html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_static_path = ['_static']

autodoc_mock_imports = ['asdf']
nitpicky = True

#nitpick_ignore = [
#    ('py:class', 'foo.FOO'),
#]
```

[image]

When I run `make html SPHINXOPTS=-Ea` I get the resulting documentation.

But I would expect that when I mock the import that foo.FOO is documented (see picture above).

Sphinx: 4.3.0

Is this a feature or a Bug?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. A workaround is to add `FOO.__doc__ = "Foo constant."` in foo.py.

Comment: Thanks, but in that case i suspect that it really is a sphinx bug.

Comment: The issue is closed now: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/9883

Comment: Yes, thanks, I saw that but I could not test it since it is not released yet.

Comment: @mzjn Do you know how to handle the question if this was a bug? Close, Delete, Resolve, ...?

Comment: You can add an answer if you want. That is what I would do (especially since the question has been upvoted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a bug and has been fixed https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/9905